# Calculating average time between dates in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, mariadb, window-functions

Using MySQL, I'm trying to figure out how to answer the question: **What is the average number of months between users creating their Nth project?**

Expected result:

```
| project count | Average # months |
| 1             | 0                | # On average, it took 0 months to create the first project (nothing to compare to)
| 2             | 12               | # On average, it takes a user 12 months to create their second project
| 3             | 3                | # On average, it takes a user 3 months to create their third project
```

My MySQL table represents projects created by users. The table can be summarized as:

```
| user_id | project created at |
|---------|--------------------|
| 1       | Jan 1, 2020 1:00 pm|
| 1       | Feb 2, 2020 3:45 am|
| 1       | Nov 6, 2020 0:01 am|
| 1       | Mar 4, 2021 5:01 pm|
|------------------------------|
| 2       | Another timestamp  |
| 2       | Another timestamp  |
| 2       | Another timestamp  |
| 2       | Another timestamp  |
| 2       | Another timestamp  |
| 2       | Another timestamp  |
|------------------------------|
| ...     | Another timestamp  |
| ...     | Another timestamp  |
```

Some users will have one project while some may have hundreds.

### Edit: Current Implementation

```sql
with
    paid_self_serve_projects_presentation as (
        select 
                `Paid Projects`.owner_email
            `Owner Email`, 
                row_number() over (partition by `Paid Projects`.owner_uuid order by created_at)
            `Project Count`,
                day(`Paid Projects`.created_at)
            `Created Day`,
                month(`Paid Projects`.created_at)
            `Created Month`,
                year(`Paid Projects`.created_at)
            `Created Year`,
                `Paid Projects`.created_at
            `Created`
        from self_service_paid_projects as `Paid Projects`
        order by `Paid Projects`.owner_uuid, `Paid Projects`.created_at
    )
    
select `Projects`.* from paid_self_serve_projects_presentation as `Projects`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions. I am thinking `row_number()` to enumerate the projects of each user ordered by creation date, and `lag()` to get the date when the previous project was created:

```
select rn, avg(datediff(created_at, lag_created_at)) avg_diff_days
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by user_id order by created_at) rn,
        lag(created_at, 1, created_at) over(partition by user_id order by created_at) lag_created_at
    from mytable t
) t
group by rn
```

This gives you the average difference in days, which is somehow more accurates that months. If you really want months, then use `timestampdiff(month, lag_created_at, created_at)` instead of `datediff()` - but be aware that the function returns an integer value, hence there is a loss of precision.

Comment: Thanks, @gmb. I'll try to tie in what you provided and circle back with any questions. I updated my description with the code I'd been hacking away at.

Comment: In MariaDB I can see the date output if I use `lag(created_at)`. I get a syntax error with what you provided: `lag(created_at, 1, created_at)`.  Just want to be sure that I'm not missing something critical by dropping the last two arguments.

Comment: @TylersSN: indeed, the tree-arguments forms of `LAG()` is supported by MySQL, not MariaDB. You can replace it with `coalesce(lag(created_at) over(partition by user_id order by created_at), created_at)`. But basically this is just there to have `0` on the first project per user - with the expression you used (`lag(created_at) over...)`), you will get `null` instead.

Comment: Given that null is ignored, I think I can get by with `lag(created_at)`. Thanks so much for this! This is now working as expected and far less complicated than I had expected!